# Get value from URL using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there is a many methods to do this in Angularjs. For example by using $location etc.

But I am unable to find how to get value if URL looks like this:

http://localhost:8000/test/1

How to get value one from that URL?

For routing I am using stateProvider:

```
export default angular.module("examino.userTestSession", ["ui.router"])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("testing", {
                url: "/test",
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
            .state("sessionExpired", {
                url: "/sessionExpired",
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session-expired.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            });
    })
```

Can I maybe get that value when defining "testing" state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the route parameters with `:param`

**Routes**

```
export default angular.module("examino.userTestSession", ["ui.router"])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("testing", {
                url: "/test/:id", //Add the parameter here
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
            .state("sessionExpired", {
                url: "/sessionExpired",
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session-expired.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            });
    })
```

**Controller**

```
var myId = $stateParams.id
```

**Notes**

`/test/:id` will match `/test/bob`, `/test/1235` and `/test/` but not `/test` or `/test/bob/other`

`/test/{id}` is the same as the previous one

`/test/{id:int}` means that the param is interpreted as an integer

`/test/{id:[0-9]{1,8}}` means that the id must respect the regex provided